# Is there a good way to create and use a 'Template' in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

Our projects in our company are all built based off a thing we call a 'Project Scaffold'. It's got all the base required code for all sites, basic folder structure and all other things similar to that.

At the moment, we have a repository for this 'Project Scaffold' and each time we want to create a new project, we copy this project into a new folder, and rename all occurrences of the name 'ProjectScaffold' within the project. As you can tell, this is quite time consuming and can sometimes cause errors if we miss out a single occurrence of 'ProjectScaffold'.

This project will need to have all the default dependencies which is why having a full project that we copy is working for us at the moment.

I have looked into the possibility of creating a visual studio template but I can't seem to find a good way of accomplishing it.

We have been thinking if there was a way to possibly implement it through a NuGet Package, however I feel as if this would be either extremely difficult or impossible.

If possible, it would also be something that would be usable in Visual Studio 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `File-->Export Template` :)

You can then customize the generated zip file to suit your needs.

More on this on the [Creating Project and Item templates on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx)